# Set Application Icon

Tags: application-development, icons, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

I'm building a QML application with the Ubuntu SDK.  I've figured out how to add an application icon to the `.desktop` file, but I'm not sure where to add the window icon itself.  I've seen code for setting `Applicaton.windowIcon` with C++, but I'm just using QML/JS.  How can I add my icon to the application configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the icon in your `.desktop` file *is* adding it to your application configuration, so I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  As long as the icon is installed with everything else, you should be all set.  If you're installing via a click package, a relative file name for the icon in the `.desktop` file is all you need; otherwise, you may want to use an absolute path.

If you're trying to get the icon set for a program that isn't installed, you can add the desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications/`.  IIRC, this file won't be immediately detected, but it will be loaded eventually.  Logging out and then back in will probably force a refresh.

If you want to adjust the icon programmatically while the application is running, I can't help you.  I'd be surprised if you could do that through pure QML, but it might be easy to write a C++ plugin.

Comment: Okay, I suppose that's sufficient.  I was just thinking about native applications like Inkscape.  When you open Inkscape from the terminal, the icon appears in the launcher properly.  If I were to launch my app without using the .desktop launcher, the icon does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

First add the icon to a resource file. Your *assets.qrc* may look like this

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="assets/">
         <file alias="logo.png">assets/icons/logo.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Next you need to set the application icon on the C++ side

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGuiApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/assets/logo.png"));
    // next do whatever is needed to set up the qml engine
}
```

This should effectively set the application icon. On my Ubuntu machine, the application icon appears in two places when the app is running

- [on the side panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k4qK.png)
- [on the top panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEry4.png)